# Display a PHP parent Class Variable

Tags: php, class, object, derived-class

I would like to display a parent Class variable, I can't find a way to solve the situtation...

Here is my PHP :

```
class A {

    public $a;

}

class B extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        echo $parent->a;
    }

}

$B = new B();
```

This is supposed to output $a, in my case $a is an PDO object, and instead of print it, i call a prepare() on it :)

like that :

```
class A {

    public $a;

}

class B extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->a->prepare('random SQL request');
    }

}

$B = new B();
```

I have a `"Cannot access empty property"` PHP error

Thanks !

Comment: What is the output of this? What errors or problems occur?

Comment: change $parent to $this and take a look at oop-basics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
class A {

    public $a = "Hello World";

}

class B extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        echo $this->a;
    }

}

$B = new B();
```

Run it:

> php parent.php
>
> Hello World

Comment: think we still need more code to understand what you're trying to do. Show us what's in the A class.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $this->a;
```

Many times the comments in the PHP manual are as valuable as the manual itself:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php#42153